2007 Dodge Ram 5.7 AC blowing hot
May AC is blowing hot.
Compressor runs without disengaging.
Condenser fan is functioning.
High pressure line coming from compressor is hot to the touch.
High pressure line near the firewall is very cold.
All other lines are ambient temperature.
I checked pressures and this is what I have:
Ambient temperature is 95F
Static low side is 85psi
Static high side is 85psi
Ac System on:
Low side is 10psi
High Side is 175psi
Is this most likely indicative of a blocked orifice tube, low refrigerant, both?

Confirm that the temperature control is set to cold (blue?). Explain what you mean by "blowing hot." Do you mean ambient temperature like 95F? Or do you mean actual heat like 140F? If it's actual heat, perhaps your blend door is stuck or out of calibration. Try moving temperature control all the way cold-hot-cold. Does the blower sound change? Does the temperature change?

In addition to MTAs questions, was this ac repaired or serviced by you or repair shop? Was sealer used? Some vehicles require above idle rpm when measuring low and high side pressures. What parts were replaced? Was oil flushed out in a major repair? Orifice tube replaced? Accumulator/drier replaced? Correct amount of new oil used in major repair(s)? After repairs, was this system evacuated before refilling with refrigerant? While ac repair isn't rocket science, it's not diy friendly. If topping off periodically, this may be a leak that wasn't addressed with loss of refrigerant.
